# laravel 4 Call to a member function posts() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel-4

I followed some tutorial on http://culttt.com/2013/05/13/setting-up-your-first-laravel-4-model/ and it just won't work. Here's what I tried:

Post model:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

  protected $fillable = array('body');

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/posts',function()
{
  // Create a new Post
  $post = new Post(array('body' => 'Yada yada yada'));
  // Grab User 1
  $user = User::find(1);
  // Save the Post
  $user->posts()->save($post);
});
```

User model:

```
/**
 * Post relationship
 */
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

For Post model, just simply creating a body column and a `user_id` column. But, when I browser, display errors: "Call to a member function posts() on a non-object"

Would anyone know what the problem here is?

Comment: Does the user with ID = 1 exist in the database?

Comment: @Janily did you get this sorted? try running `dd($user);` after `$user = User::find(1);` and post the output this will allow you to see the user object and help work out whats happening. Also have you looked at your database. Does the user exist with an id of 1? If you have recreated the user a couple of times the id may have been incremented. You could try `User::first();` instead to see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the User before you attempt to retrieve it from the database.

Try:

```
 // Create a User
 $user = new User;
 $user->username = 'username';
 $user->email = 'email@domain.com';
 $user->password = 'password';
 $user->password_confirmation = 'password';
 $user->save();

 // Create a new Post
 $post = new Post(array('body' => 'Yada yada yada'));
 // Grab User 1
 $user = User::find(1);
 // Save the Post
 $user->posts()->save($post);
```